# Why need to add var data before the geojson file?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm confused about the geojson file when I need load the geojson data from local file.

The original data is {geojson data}.

And I must add a `var data = {geojson data}` before the geojson data manually.

Is there any way to avoid this process and direct load the geojson file?

Comment: hey, can you show how you load that gojson data after line you mentioned above

Comment: `geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
   style: style,
   onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(map);`

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be interested in [leaflet-ajax plugin](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax):

> Allows you to call JSON via an Ajax call.

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("geojson.json");
```